# Stringreading software for PHP Gettext strings

Tags: php, macos, translation, gettext

Currently I'm in a major project which has several thousands of PHP gettext like translations

`_("blabla I'm an English source file")`

These lines will be translated with PO Files generated by PO Edit. However, we have an english gammer nazi which is going to check all of our grammar and correct spelling mistakes. However the grammer nazi is not really into coding and it would be nice to have a large list with all the `__("blabla")` strings.

So basically I'm looking for a tool which can read all my PHP Files (much like PO edit) and make it a readable list that can be edited and saved (back to the PHP files).

Is there such a tool? Or am I doomed and do I create it myself?

I prefer OSX since were all using it here, but something windowsish would be fine.

Comment: Perhaps create english translation file with corrected grammar?

Comment: Yah, that would be an option. However we spend such a huge amount of time to it, that i'd love to have the source in a descent way. We're speaking on a communication level difference. We have several writing styles throughout the site. From exaggerated American arrogance to British politeness on a business level. So thats the reason we want to clear things out.

Comment: Well, if you replace messages in source, other translations will be broken. Even if you don't have other language versions yet, problem will arise in future releases of your software

Comment: That's the exact reason we want to change the source. We didn't start on translating to other languages yet. We want the "source" to be clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use English like you use your other translations and create a po file for it. This way your English grammer person can also change whole sentences now and later without actually affecting the code. And you can at some point add different english versions (e.g. en-US, en-GB).

Answer (score 0):

How about the `xgettext` util described [here](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=xgettext).

Comment: Thanks for you help, that would be sort of an option. The problem is, that we need to put it back aswell. Any change on that? An alternative way with another tool will do aswel!